# Negative Lookahead - Find the Last Occurrence Of String

Tags: regex

I need to find the last occurrence of a RegEx pattern. I think that Negative Lookahead can be used but I can't figure out how it works.

Please help.

Pattern: ###\s\d+/\d+\s-\s\w+\s\d+,\s\d{4}

Desired result: "### 2/14 - July 30, 2021"

Sample text:

```
# Note Title

Bunch of text

### 1/14 - July 30, 2021

More text. Blah blah.

### 2/14 - July 30, 2021
```

Answer (score 0):

You could phrase the last occurrence by using a negative lookahead which asserts that the target pattern does not occur again later in the input:

```regex
###\s\d+/\d+\s-\s\w+\s\d+,\s\d{4}(?!.*###\s\d+/\d+\s-\s\w+\s\d+,\s\d{4})
```

### Demo

Note that I assume in the above pattern that dot all mode would be enabled.  If your regex tool doesn't support dot all mode, then replace the `.*` in the negative lookahead with `[\s\S]*`.